# PHP checking if server is alive

Tags: php

I need to check if a group of servers, routers and switches is alive. I have been searching for something reliable that would work with IPs and ports for over an hour now, could anyone help?

Ended up using

```
function ping($addr, $port='') {
    if(empty($port)) {
        ob_start();
        system('ping -c1 -w1 '.$addr, $return);
        ob_end_clean();
        if($return == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        $fp = fsockopen("udp://{$addr}", $port, $errno, $errstr);
        if (!$fp) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could replace line 6 with         return $return === 0;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Servers, routers and switches...the one commonality that all of them share is the ability to accept SNMP requests if an SNMP service is running.  Sounds like what you are trying to do is implement a funny workaround to a monitoring system (nagios, etc....)

As per:  http://php.net/manual/en/book.snmp.php

```
 <?php
 $endpoints = array('10.0.0.1','10.0.0.2','10.0.0.3','10.0.0.4','10.0.0.5');
 foreach ($endpoints as $endpoint) {
      $session = new SNMP(SNMP::VERSION_2c, $endpoint, 'boguscommunity');
      var_dump($session->getError());
      // do something with the $session->getError() if it exists else, endpoint is up
 }
 ?>
```

This will tell you if the endpoint is alive and the SNMP service is running.  Specific to seeing if the port is available / open, you can use `fsockopen()`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php

```
 <?php
 $fp = fsockopen("udp://127.0.0.1", 13, $errno, $errstr);
 if (!$fp) {
      echo "ERROR: $errno - $errstr<br />\n";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Im not to sure what endpoints are for? This is network monitor script, so all i'd have is an IP and port, or a http address, would this work with fsockopen? as SNMP will require additional server installation

Comment: "I need to check if group of servers, routers and switches" ... `$endpoints` is a placeholder where you can define them all.  Giving you ideas on how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ip = "123.456.789.0";
$ping = exec("ping -c 1 -s 64 -t 64 ".$ip);

var_dump($ping);

// and so forth.
```

Comment: returns an element thats blank, no matter what IP I put in?

Comment: £exec doesnt seem to be returning anything

Comment: That's weird. Are you using Windows by any chance?

Comment: try putting the full path to `ping`.  it may not be in the path of PHP by default.

Comment: I think exec() is disallowed by the host :/

Comment: refer to the answer by @sdolgy then, it's probably cleaner anyways.

Answer (score 0):

if you are checking for mysql you can use something like

```
    if (mysqli_ping($ip))  echo "sweet!";  
    else echo "oh dam";
```

I would be a little concerned using the ping option as that can be blocked, and out of no where ...

Comment: I think is more credibly a comment: neither a router nor a switch would be running MySQL.

Comment: No I totally agree, I just wanted put this in the mix of options in case someone is really just checking for SQL or something.