# Checking for server availability

Tags: php, fsockopen

Trying to take the address from the database and written in an array, but always says Bad, all servers are available.

```
include('config.php');
$query_select = "select `ip` from `server`";
$result_select = mysql_query($query_select);
$host=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_select,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    foreach ($row as $r){
       $host[$r] = $r;
     }
}
foreach ($host as $h){
    $waitTimeoutInSeconds = 1; 
        if($fp = fsockopen($h,$waitTimeoutInSeconds)){   
              echo 'good';
        } else {
              echo 'bad'; 
                } 
fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP checking if server is alive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792413/php-checking-if-server-is-alive)

Comment: Don't you need to specify a port and protocol?

Comment: no it works without it